# Dúvidas com o inserir

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um `form` a inserir em três tabelas diferentes:

```html
<form name="customer_details" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()" >
<h5><strong>Utente</strong></h5> <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Primeiro e último nome" style="width:300px" required />
<h5><strong>Nº Utente</strong></h5> <input type="text" id="codigoutente" name="codigoutente" style="width:80px" required />
<h5><strong>Valência</strong></h5>
<select name="codvalencia" required>
       <option></option>
  <?php  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.Valencia ORDER BY Valencia ASC"; 
  $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
  while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){ 
  echo '<option value="'.$ln['CodValencia'].'"> '.$ln['Valencia'].'</option>';  
  }
  ?>   
</select>
<h5><strong>Responsável</strong></h5> <input type="text" id="Responsavel" name="Responsavel" style="width:350px" required />
<h5><strong>Contato</strong></h5> 
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">351</span> <input type="text" class="input" id="Contato" name="Contato" style="width:150px" required />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Registo"/>
</form>
```

Código para inserir:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome']; 
$codigoutente = $_POST['codigoutente']; 
$codvalencia = $_POST['codvalencia']; 
$Responsavel = $_POST['Responsavel'];
$Contato = $_POST['Contato']; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO UtentesCons (`nome`,`codvalencia`,`codigoutente`) VALUES ('$nome','$codvalencia','$codigoutente')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Responsaveis (`Responsavel`,`IdUtente`) VALUES ('$Responsavel','$codigoutente')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ContatoRes (`IdUtente`,`IdResponsavel`,`Contato`) VALUES ('$codigoutente','$last_id','351$Contato')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
```

Até aqui está a funcionar corretamente.
Agora acrescentei mais um `form` antes do `input` do `submit`:

```html
<input id="botao" style="float: right;" class="botao1" onclick="addresp()" value="Adicionar Responsável"/>
 
<div id="novoresp">

</div>


<div class="teste" id="respform" hidden> 

<h5><strong>Responsável</strong></h5> <input type="text" id="Responsavel" name="Responsavel" style="width:350px"/>

<h5><strong>Contato</strong></h5> 
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">351</span> <input type="text" class="input" id="Contato" name="Contato" style="width:150px"/>
</div> 
</div>
```

Pretendia que caso tenha mais do que um novo responsável, o `form novoresp` também inserisse nas mesmas tabelas do primeiro form, nestas duas:

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Responsaveis (`Responsavel`,`IdUtente`) VALUES ('$Responsavel','$codigoutente')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ContatoRes (`IdUtente`,`IdResponsavel`,`Contato`) VALUES ('$codigoutente','$last_id','351$Contato')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheguei à solução criando dois `for`, no segundo e terceiro `insert`, e tornando o `insert_id` em um `array`, como o campo `Responsavel` e `Contato` dos `form`:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome']; 
$codigoutente = $_POST['codigoutente']; 
$codvalencia = $_POST['codvalencia']; 
$Responsavel = $_POST['Responsavel'];
$Contato = $_POST['Contato']; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO UtentesCons (`nome`,`codvalencia`,`codigoutente`) VALUES ('$nome','$codvalencia','$codigoutente')");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["Responsavel"]);$i++) { 
$Responsavel = $_POST['Responsavel'][$i];

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Responsaveis (`Responsavel`,`IdUtente`) VALUES ('$Responsavel','$codigoutente')");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
$last_id_array[] = $conn->insert_id;
}

for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["Contato"]);$i++) { 
$Contato = $_POST['Contato'][$i];
$last_id = $last_id_array[$i];

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ContatoRes (`IdUtente`,`IdResponsavel`,`Contato`) VALUES ('$codigoutente','$last_id','351$Contato')");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fala iniciante ! Tudo bom brother ? Então! o que eu faria no seu caso...

Você pegaria os dados dos outros responsaveis, normalmente por meio do **$_POST**.
No codigo de execução do PHP *(Aonde você insere seus dados)* você iria inserir esses novos responsaveis **SE** existir novos responsaveis *(Ou seja, utilizando o IF)*, Vamos lá !

```
$nome = $_POST['nome']; 
$codigoutente = $_POST['codigoutente']; 
$codvalencia = $_POST['codvalencia']; 
$Responsavel = $_POST['Responsavel'];
$Contato = $_POST['Contato']; 
$NOVOresponsavel = $_POST['novoResponsavel']; //Note que aqui eu mudei o ID do form para não ficar igual ao responsavel principal, então mude no codigo HTML o id.
$NOVOcontato = $_POST['novoContato']; //Mesma situacao do $NOVOresponsavel.

if ($NOVOresponsavel != null && $NOVOcontato != null){    
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO UtentesCons (`nome`,`codvalencia`,`codigoutente`) VALUES ('$nome','$codvalencia','$codigoutente')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Responsaveis (`Responsavel`,`IdUtente`) VALUES ('$Responsavel','$codigoutente')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;

$stmt1NOVO = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Responsaveis (`Responsavel`,`IdUtente`) VALUES ('$NOVOresponsavel','$codigoutente')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1); // Vai adicionar o novo responsavel POREM com a variavel que voce pegou do novo form.


$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ContatoRes (`IdUtente`,`IdResponsavel`,`Contato`) VALUES ('$codigoutente','$last_id','351$Contato')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);

$stmt2NOVO = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ContatoRes (`IdUtente`,`IdResponsavel`,`Contato`) VALUES ('$codigoutente','$last_id','351$NOVOcontato')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2); // Mesma situação do $stmt1NOVO.
} else {  //Ou seja, se não houver novo responsavel, roda o codigo normal 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO UtentesCons (`nome`,`codvalencia`,`codigoutente`)         VALUES ('$nome','$codvalencia','$codigoutente')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Responsaveis (`Responsavel`,`IdUtente`) VALUES ('$Responsavel','$codigoutente')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ContatoRes (`IdUtente`,`IdResponsavel`,`Contato`) VALUES ('$codigoutente','$last_id','351$Contato')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
}
```

Resumindo... as linhas de codigo que eu adicionei foram...

```
$NOVOresponsavel = $_POST['novoResponsavel']; //Note que aqui eu mudei o ID do form para não ficar igual ao responsavel principal, então mude no codigo HTML o id.
$NOVOcontato = $_POST['novoContato']; //Mesma situacao do $NOVOresponsavel.

if ($NOVOresponsavel != null && $NOVOcontato != null){ 

$stmt1NOVO = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Responsaveis (`Responsavel`,`IdUtente`) VALUES ('$NOVOresponsavel','$codigoutente')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1); // Vai adicionar o novo responsavel POREM com a variavel que voce pegou do novo form.

$stmt2NOVO = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ContatoRes (`IdUtente`,`IdResponsavel`,`Contato`) VALUES ('$codigoutente','$last_id','351$NOVOcontato')");    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2); // Mesma situação do $stmt1NOVO.
} else {  //Ou seja, se não houver novo responsavel, roda o codigo normal
```

Espero ter ajudado !! Boa sorte e otimo estudos.